# Using d3js to calculate midpoints and curve path for quadratic SVG connectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am trying to show connections from rectangles on left to rectangles on right. The rectangles on both sides are dynamically constructed based on values in JSON. 
Currently I have placed empty divs on left and right end side of rectangles and using this as reference to obtain x,y co-ordinates and used this to  draw a quadratic SVG curve.
While this does the job , i wanted to know if i could improve the way i calculate the curve path.

Calculation of SVG curve is based on the answer found here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286885/9924482.
This works but I wanted to know if d3js could automatically construct a connector given two points.If it could calculate the midpoint i am sure the connections would be smoother than my calculation.

```
function x() {
    var p1x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("au").getAttribute("cx"));
    var p1y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("au").getAttribute("cy"));
    var p2x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sl").getAttribute("cx"));
    var p2y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sl").getAttribute("cy"));

    // mid-point of line:
    var mpx = (p2x + p1x) * 0.5;
    var mpy = (p2y + p1y) * 0.5;

    // angle of perpendicular to line:
    var theta = Math.atan2(p2y - p1y, p2x - p1x) - Math.PI / 2;

    // distance of control point from mid-point of line:
    var offset = 30;

    // location of control point:
    var c1x = mpx + offset * Math.cos(theta);
    var c1y = mpy + offset * Math.sin(theta);

    // show where the control point is:
    var c1 = document.getElementById("cp");
    c1.setAttribute("cx", c1x);
    c1.setAttribute("cy", c1y);

    // construct the command to draw a quadratic curve
    var curve = "M" + p1x + " " + p1y + " Q " + c1x + " " + c1y + " " + p2x + " " + p2y;
    var curveElement = document.getElementById("curve");
    curveElement.setAttribute("d", curve);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear in your question how many control points you want. If you want to create links with an inflection point, the most comfortable solution is using D3 [link generators](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#links).

For instance, suppose you have this data:

```
const data = [{x: 20, y: 20}, {x: 280, y: 130}];
```

You can use a link generator like this:

```
const linkGenerator = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y)
  .source(d => d[0])
  .target(d => d[1]);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const data = [{
  x: 20,
  y: 20
}, {
  x: 280,
  y: 130
}];
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const linkGenerator = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y)
  .source(d => d[0])
  .target(d => d[1]);
const circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", d => d.x)
  .attr("cy", d => d.y);
const link = svg.append("path")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .attr("d", linkGenerator(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

And here another demo, with random data:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const linkGenerator = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y)
  .source(d => d[0])
  .target(d => d[1]);
draw();
d3.select("button").on("click", draw);

function draw() {
  const data = [{
    x: 20,
    y: 20 + Math.random() * 110
  }, {
    x: 280,
    y: 20 + Math.random() * 110
  }];
  const circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data);
  circles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .merge(circles)
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  const link = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data([data]);
  link.enter()
    .append("path")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .merge(link)
    .attr("d", linkGenerator(data))
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button>Change data</button>
<br>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: @John You don't have enough points to upvote. But thanks anyway!

Comment: This worked and the diagram that was generated in your second case (where random points are created) is similar to what i want to achieve. The downside of implementing this in a project is  i have to use d3 v4.60 and lineGenerator was not supported . I tried looking at d3.line() here - https://devdocs.io/d3~4/d3-shape#line   but could not make progress on achieving the functionality of linkGenerator() function. Any suggestions would be helpful. 

Thank you

Comment: @John Answering this in the comments section is not possible. I suggest you post this as a *new question*.