# D3 retrieving rect vertices for appending parallelograms (polygons)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My goal here is to draw parallelograms connecting the rank of one company in one business quarter to its new rank in the next business quarter. I am using rects to represent each company or `manager`. (each column is a business quarter). My steps/progress:

- used `.each()` to store the parallelograms vertices by retrieving each rect's `.attr()` for `x`,`y` and `height`.
- Since the order of companies is different for each column, I had to store these x & y coordinates into two arrays.
- Then I had to merge them on the condition that the xs and ys belonged to the same manager. (for example, `Fidelity` goes from being #1 to #2 after the first column).

This is where the trouble began, basically, my `y1`s and `y0`s are all stuck at the same value and I'm not sure why.

```js
  

var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var outerRadius = (400 / 2);
var innerRadius = 15;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+ ")");

var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([.01,.09])
    .range([7,50]);
/*
var tsvData = d3.tsv('market-share-change.tsv');

tsvData.then(function(rawData) {

    var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
      return { manager:d.manager, t1:+d.t1, t2:+d.t2, t3:+d.t3}
    });

})
*/

var data = [[{'manager': 'Mirae Asset', 'share': 0.016},
  {'manager': 'Manulife', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'ChinaAMC', 'share': 0.012},
  {'manager': 'Principal', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'Aberdeen Standard', 'share': 0.013},
  {'manager': 'CSOP', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'BOCI-Prudential', 'share': 0.019},
  {'manager': 'Allianz', 'share': 0.016},
  {'manager': 'HSBC', 'share': 0.027},
  {'manager': 'Deutsche Bank', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'Invesco', 'share': 0.025},
  {'manager': 'First State', 'share': 0.033},
  {'manager': 'JP Morgan', 'share': 0.041},
  {'manager': 'Value Partners', 'share': 0.04},
  {'manager': 'Schroders', 'share': 0.051},
  {'manager': 'Hang Seng', 'share': 0.063},
  {'manager': 'UBS', 'share': 0.056},
  {'manager': 'SSgA', 'share': 0.066},
  {'manager': 'Fidelity', 'share': 0.088},
  {'manager': 'BlackRock', 'share': 0.084}],
 [{'manager': 'Mirae Asset', 'share': 0.013},
  {'manager': 'Manulife', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'ChinaAMC', 'share': 0.013},
  {'manager': 'Principal', 'share': 0.018},
  {'manager': 'Aberdeen Standard', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'CSOP', 'share': 0.019},
  {'manager': 'BOCI-Prudential', 'share': 0.02},
  {'manager': 'Allianz', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'HSBC', 'share': 0.023},
  {'manager': 'Deutsche Bank', 'share': 0.02},
  {'manager': 'Invesco', 'share': 0.02},
  {'manager': 'First State', 'share': 0.029},
  {'manager': 'JP Morgan', 'share': 0.04},
  {'manager': 'Value Partners', 'share': 0.039},
  {'manager': 'Schroders', 'share': 0.051},
  {'manager': 'Hang Seng', 'share': 0.063},
  {'manager': 'UBS', 'share': 0.055},
  {'manager': 'SSgA', 'share': 0.065},
  {'manager': 'Fidelity', 'share': 0.088},
  {'manager': 'BlackRock', 'share': 0.101}],
 [{'manager': 'Mirae Asset', 'share': 0.012},
  {'manager': 'Manulife', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'ChinaAMC', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'Principal', 'share': 0.017},
  {'manager': 'Aberdeen Standard', 'share': 0.017},
  {'manager': 'CSOP', 'share': 0.018},
  {'manager': 'BOCI-Prudential', 'share': 0.018},
  {'manager': 'Allianz', 'share': 0.018},
  {'manager': 'HSBC', 'share': 0.023},
  {'manager': 'Deutsche Bank', 'share': 0.023},
  {'manager': 'Invesco', 'share': 0.023},
  {'manager': 'First State', 'share': 0.029},
  {'manager': 'JP Morgan', 'share': 0.041},
  {'manager': 'Value Partners', 'share': 0.044},
  {'manager': 'Schroders', 'share': 0.048},
  {'manager': 'Hang Seng', 'share': 0.056},
  {'manager': 'UBS', 'share': 0.061},
  {'manager': 'SSgA', 'share': 0.062},
  {'manager': 'Fidelity', 'share': 0.087},
  {'manager': 'BlackRock', 'share': 0.096}]];

  var poly = [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ];

  var multiPoly1 = d3.range(20).map(()=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(poly)));
  var multiPoly2 = d3.range(20).map(()=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(poly)));


/*
    for (var k=0; k <(data[0].length); k++) {
    polyMaster[0][k].push({'manager':data[0][k].manager})
  };
*/
  var colorMap = {
    'Fidelity':"#003366",
    'BlackRock':"#366092",
    'SSgA':"#4f81b9",
    'Hang Seng':"#95b3d7",
    'UBS':"#b8cce4",
    'Schroders':"#e7eef8",
    'JP Morgan':"#a6a6a6",
    'Value Partners':"#d9d9d9",
    'Yuanta':"#ffffcc",
    'First State':"#ffffcc",
    'HSBC':'#f6d18b',
    'Invesco':'#e4a733',
    'BOCI-Prudential':"#b29866",
    'Allianz':'#a6a6a6',
    'Mirae Asset':'#d9d9d9',
    'Manulife':'#e7eef8',
    'CSOP':'#b8cce4',
    'Principal':'#95b3d7',
    'Deutsche Bank':'#4f81b9',
    'Aberdeen Standard':'#366092',
    'ChinaAMC':'#003366'
  };

    for (var j=0; j <(data.length); j++) {

    var className = "column"+String(j);

    let counterRect = 0,
      counterText = 0;

      var spacing = 170;

      var sortedData = data[j].sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.share - a.share;
      });

        var column = graphGroup.selectAll(className)
            .data(sortedData)
            .attr('class', className)
          .enter().append("g");

        column.append("rect")
            .attr('class','rect'+String(j))
            .attr("width", 120)
            .attr("height", function(d) {
              return heightScale(d.share)
            })
            .attr('x', function(d) {return j*spacing})
            .attr('y', function(d, i) {
              let previous = counterRect;
              return (counterRect += heightScale(d.share)+2, previous)
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==0) {
                multiPoly1[i][0].x = 120;
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==0) {
                multiPoly1[i][0].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==0) {
                multiPoly1[i][1].x = 120;
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==0) {
                multiPoly1[i][1].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'))+parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('height'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==1) {
                multiPoly2[i][1].x = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==1) {
                multiPoly2[i][1].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==1) {
                multiPoly2[i][0].x = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==1) {
                multiPoly2[i][0].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'))+parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('height'));
              }
            })
            .style('fill',function(d,i) {return colorMap[d.manager]});

            column.append("text")
              .attr('x', function(d) {return j*spacing+60})
              .attr('y', function(d, i) {
                let previous = counterText;
                return (counterText += heightScale(d.share)+2, previous + (heightScale(d.share)/2))
              })
              .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
              .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
              .text(function(d) {
                return d.manager;
              });

              var managerList = [];
              for (var k = 0; k < sortedData.length; k++)
                  managerList.push({'manager':sortedData[k].manager});

              var tempList1 = [];
              for (var k = 0; k < managerList.length; k++)
                  tempList1.push({'manager': managerList[k], 'x1': multiPoly1[k][0].x, 'y1':multiPoly1[k][0].y, 'x2':multiPoly1[k][1].x, 'y2':multiPoly1[k][1].y });

              var tempList2 = [];
              for (var k = 0; k < managerList.length; k++)
                  tempList2.push({'manager': managerList[k], 'x3': multiPoly2[k][1].x, 'y3':multiPoly2[k][1].y, 'x4':multiPoly2[k][0].x, 'y4':multiPoly2[k][0].y });

              var combinedList = [];



              const list1ByManager = tempList1.reduce((a, item) => {
                a[item.manager] = item;
                return a;
              }, {});

              var combinedList = tempList2.map((item2) => ({
                ...list1ByManager[item2.manager],
                ...item2
              }));

              console.log(combinedList)

    var polyMaster = [];

    for (var k = 0; k < managerList.length; k++) {
        var tempItem = [
          {'x':combinedList[k].x1, 'y':combinedList[k].y1},
          {'x':combinedList[k].x2, 'y':combinedList[k].y2},
          {'x':combinedList[k].x3, 'y':combinedList[k].y3},
          {'x':combinedList[k].x4, 'y':combinedList[k].y4},
        ];
        polyMaster.push(tempItem);
    }

              console.log(polyMaster)

            };

graphGroup.selectAll("polygon")
    .data(polyMaster)
  .enter().append("polygon")
    .attr("points",function(d) {
        return d.map(function(d) { return [d.x,d.y].join(","); }).join(" ");})
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width",2);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Examining `tempList1` and `tempList2` in the console log confirms I have indeed stored all the values correctly, but for some reason when I try to merge these two arrays into `combinedList` the `y`s are not merged properly. Relevant code:

```
          var combinedList = [];



          const list1ByManager = tempList1.reduce((a, item) => {
            a[item.manager] = item;
            return a;
          }, {});

          var combinedList = tempList2.map((item2) => ({
            ...list1ByManager[item2.manager],
            ...item2
          }));
```

### Question

Did I merge `tempList1` and `tempList2` incorrectly? Why are the `y`s not preserved as shown in the snippet?

(In other words the parallelograms (in black) should not be all drawn at the bottom of the first column, they should attach perfectly to the corresponding companies -- forming a bridge if you will, making it easy for the eye to see the rank change in any one company by tracing the company's position in the first column to its new position in the second column)

**Note:** I'm just concerned with the parallelograms between column one and two for now. I'm not going to try with column three until I get this much figured out.

Comment: Use D3 link generators (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44760465/5768908) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56927279/5768908)). That's the best advice I can offer. That being said, I'm voting to close this question as *too broad*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Judging from the documentation, link generators only seem to produce lines, or is there parallelogram link methods?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado The key thing is I need it to have rigid lines and 2 dimensional (parallogram), and not curvy lines.

Comment: Well, you'll have to create your own path then (or a skewed rectangle). Now the question is even more broad.

Comment: Updated with substantial progress.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Could you add a representative sample data and a sketch showing what you would like the end result to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but it is hideous, not succinct at all. I had to go with it in the interest of time. I may revisit this code soon, and I would be keen to see if others have improvements in mind.

Most glaring of the heretical code is populating the objects by brute force. I kept encountering a bug where I couldn't create an object with a comprehension or for loop.

Even if you don't have the patience to wade through all my terrible code, you can at least see the finished result -- which looks pretty cool (if I do say so).

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var outerRadius = (400 / 2);
var innerRadius = 15;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+ ")");

var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([.01,.09])
    .range([7,50]);
/*
var tsvData = d3.tsv('market-share-change.tsv');

tsvData.then(function(rawData) {

    var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
      return { manager:d.manager, t1:+d.t1, t2:+d.t2, t3:+d.t3}
    });

})
*/

var data = [[{'manager': 'Mirae Asset', 'share': 0.016},
  {'manager': 'Manulife', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'ChinaAMC', 'share': 0.012},
  {'manager': 'Principal', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'Aberdeen Standard', 'share': 0.013},
  {'manager': 'CSOP', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'BOCI-Prudential', 'share': 0.019},
  {'manager': 'Allianz', 'share': 0.016},
  {'manager': 'HSBC', 'share': 0.027},
  {'manager': 'DWS', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'Invesco', 'share': 0.025},
  {'manager': 'First State', 'share': 0.033},
  {'manager': 'JP Morgan', 'share': 0.041},
  {'manager': 'Value Partners', 'share': 0.04},
  {'manager': 'Schroders', 'share': 0.051},
  {'manager': 'Hang Seng', 'share': 0.063},
  {'manager': 'UBS', 'share': 0.056},
  {'manager': 'SSgA', 'share': 0.066},
  {'manager': 'Fidelity', 'share': 0.088},
  {'manager': 'BlackRock', 'share': 0.084}],
 [{'manager': 'Mirae Asset', 'share': 0.013},
  {'manager': 'Manulife', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'ChinaAMC', 'share': 0.013},
  {'manager': 'Principal', 'share': 0.018},
  {'manager': 'Aberdeen Standard', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'CSOP', 'share': 0.019},
  {'manager': 'BOCI-Prudential', 'share': 0.02},
  {'manager': 'Allianz', 'share': 0.015},
  {'manager': 'HSBC', 'share': 0.023},
  {'manager': 'DWS', 'share': 0.02},
  {'manager': 'Invesco', 'share': 0.02},
  {'manager': 'First State', 'share': 0.029},
  {'manager': 'JP Morgan', 'share': 0.04},
  {'manager': 'Value Partners', 'share': 0.039},
  {'manager': 'Schroders', 'share': 0.051},
  {'manager': 'Hang Seng', 'share': 0.063},
  {'manager': 'UBS', 'share': 0.055},
  {'manager': 'SSgA', 'share': 0.065},
  {'manager': 'Fidelity', 'share': 0.088},
  {'manager': 'BlackRock', 'share': 0.101}],
 [{'manager': 'Mirae Asset', 'share': 0.012},
  {'manager': 'Manulife', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'ChinaAMC', 'share': 0.014},
  {'manager': 'Principal', 'share': 0.017},
  {'manager': 'Aberdeen Standard', 'share': 0.017},
  {'manager': 'CSOP', 'share': 0.018},
  {'manager': 'BOCI-Prudential', 'share': 0.018},
  {'manager': 'Allianz', 'share': 0.018},
  {'manager': 'HSBC', 'share': 0.023},
  {'manager': 'DWS', 'share': 0.023},
  {'manager': 'Invesco', 'share': 0.023},
  {'manager': 'First State', 'share': 0.029},
  {'manager': 'JP Morgan', 'share': 0.041},
  {'manager': 'Value Partners', 'share': 0.044},
  {'manager': 'Schroders', 'share': 0.048},
  {'manager': 'Hang Seng', 'share': 0.056},
  {'manager': 'UBS', 'share': 0.061},
  {'manager': 'SSgA', 'share': 0.062},
  {'manager': 'Fidelity', 'share': 0.087},
  {'manager': 'BlackRock', 'share': 0.096}]];

  var poly = [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ];

  var multiPoly1 = d3.range(20).map(()=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(poly)));
  var multiPoly2 = d3.range(20).map(()=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(poly)));
  var multiPoly3 = d3.range(20).map(()=>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(poly)));

/*
    for (var k=0; k <(data[0].length); k++) {
    polyMaster[0][k].push({'manager':data[0][k].manager})
  };
*/
  var colorMap = {
    'Fidelity':"#003366",
    'BlackRock':"#366092",
    'SSgA':"#4f81b9",
    'Hang Seng':"#95b3d7",
    'UBS':"#b8cce4",
    'Schroders':"#e7eef8",
    'JP Morgan':"#a6a6a6",
    'Value Partners':"#d9d9d9",
    'Yuanta':"#ffffcc",
    'First State':"#ffffcc",
    'HSBC':'#f6d18b',
    'Invesco':'#e4a733',
    'BOCI-Prudential':"#b29866",
    'Allianz':'#a6a6a6',
    'Mirae Asset':'#d9d9d9',
    'Manulife':'#e7eef8',
    'CSOP':'#b8cce4',
    'Principal':'#95b3d7',
    'DWS':'#4f81b9',
    'Aberdeen Standard':'#366092',
    'ChinaAMC':'#003366'
  };

    for (var j=0; j <(data.length); j++) {

    var className = "column"+String(j);

    let counterRect = 0,
      counterText = 0;

      var spacing = 170;

      var sortedData = data[j].sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.share - a.share;
      });

        var column = graphGroup.selectAll(className)
            .data(sortedData)
            .attr('class', className)
          .enter().append("g");

        column.append("rect")
            .attr('class','rect'+String(j))
            .attr("width", 120)
            .attr("height", function(d) {
              return heightScale(d.share)
            })
            .attr('x', function(d) {return j*spacing})
            .attr('y', function(d, i) {
              let previous = counterRect;
              return (counterRect += heightScale(d.share)+2, previous)
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==0) {
                multiPoly1[i][0].x = 120;
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==0) {
                multiPoly1[i][0].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==0) {
                multiPoly1[i][1].x = 120;
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==0) {
                multiPoly1[i][1].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'))+parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('height'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==1) {
                multiPoly2[i][1].x = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==1) {
                multiPoly2[i][1].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==1) {
                multiPoly2[i][0].x = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==1) {
                multiPoly2[i][0].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'))+parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('height'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==2) {
                multiPoly3[i][1].x = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==2) {
                multiPoly3[i][1].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==2) {
                multiPoly3[i][0].x = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x'));
              }
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
              if (j==2) {
                multiPoly3[i][0].y = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y'))+parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('height'));
              }
            })
            .style('fill',function(d,i) {return colorMap[d.manager]});

            column.append("text")
              .attr('x', function(d) {return j*spacing+60})
              .attr('y', function(d, i) {
                let previous = counterText;
                return (counterText += heightScale(d.share)+2, previous + (heightScale(d.share)/2))
              })
              .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
              .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
              .text(function(d) {
                return d.manager;
              });

              if (j==0) {
                var managerList = [];
                for (var k = 0; k < sortedData.length; k++)
                    managerList.push({'manager':sortedData[k].manager});
              }


                  if (j==0) {
                    var tempList1 = [];
                    for (var k = 0; k < managerList.length; k++)
                        tempList1.push({'manager': managerList[k], 'x1': multiPoly1[k][0].x, 'y1':multiPoly1[k][0].y, 'x2':multiPoly1[k][1].x, 'y2':multiPoly1[k][1].y });



                  }


              var tempList2 = [];
              for (var k = 0; k < managerList.length; k++)
                  tempList2.push({'manager': managerList[k], 'x3': multiPoly2[k][1].x, 'y3':multiPoly2[k][1].y, 'x4':multiPoly2[k][0].x, 'y4':multiPoly2[k][0].y });

                  if (j==2) {
                    var tempList3 = [];
                    for (var k = 0; k < managerList.length; k++) {
                      tempList3.push({'manager': managerList[k], 'x3': multiPoly3[k][1].x, 'y3':multiPoly3[k][1].y, 'x4':multiPoly3[k][0].x, 'y4':multiPoly3[k][0].y });
                    }

                  }


              //var combinedList = [];


            };

var list1Index = {};
var list2Index = {};
var list3Index = {};
var list2Index2 = {};
/*
  for (var k = 0; k < managerList.length; k++) {
    list1Index[managerList[k]] = {'x1': tempList1[k].x1, 'y1':tempList1[k].y1, 'x2':tempList1[k].x2, 'y2':tempList1[k].y2}
  };
*/

list1Index['Fidelity'] = {'x1': tempList1[0].x1, 'y1':tempList1[0].y2, 'x2':tempList1[0].x2, 'y2':tempList1[0].y1};
list1Index['BlackRock'] = {'x1': tempList1[1].x1, 'y1':tempList1[1].y2, 'x2':tempList1[1].x2, 'y2':tempList1[1].y1};
list1Index['SSgA'] = {'x1': tempList1[2].x1, 'y1':tempList1[2].y2, 'x2':tempList1[2].x2, 'y2':tempList1[2].y1};
list1Index['Hang Seng'] = {'x1': tempList1[3].x1, 'y1':tempList1[3].y2, 'x2':tempList1[3].x2, 'y2':tempList1[3].y1};
list1Index['UBS'] = {'x1': tempList1[4].x1, 'y1':tempList1[4].y2, 'x2':tempList1[4].x2, 'y2':tempList1[4].y1};
list1Index['Schroders'] = {'x1': tempList1[5].x1, 'y1':tempList1[5].y2, 'x2':tempList1[5].x2, 'y2':tempList1[5].y1};
list1Index['JP Morgan'] = {'x1': tempList1[6].x1, 'y1':tempList1[6].y2, 'x2':tempList1[6].x2, 'y2':tempList1[6].y1};
list1Index['Value Partners'] = {'x1': tempList1[7].x1, 'y1':tempList1[7].y2, 'x2':tempList1[7].x2, 'y2':tempList1[7].y1};
list1Index['First State'] = {'x1': tempList1[8].x1, 'y1':tempList1[8].y2, 'x2':tempList1[8].x2, 'y2':tempList1[8].y1};
list1Index['HSBC'] = {'x1': tempList1[9].x1, 'y1':tempList1[9].y2, 'x2':tempList1[9].x2, 'y2':tempList1[9].y1};
list1Index['Invesco'] = {'x1': tempList1[10].x1, 'y1':tempList1[10].y2, 'x2':tempList1[10].x2, 'y2':tempList1[10].y1};
list1Index['BOCI-Prudential'] = {'x1': tempList1[11].x1, 'y1':tempList1[11].y2, 'x2':tempList1[11].x2, 'y2':tempList1[11].y1};
list1Index['Allianz'] = {'x1': tempList1[12].x1, 'y1':tempList1[12].y2, 'x2':tempList1[12].x2, 'y2':tempList1[12].y1};
list1Index['Mirae Asset'] = {'x1': tempList1[13].x1, 'y1':tempList1[13].y2, 'x2':tempList1[13].x2, 'y2':tempList1[13].y1};
list1Index['Manulife'] = {'x1': tempList1[14].x1, 'y1':tempList1[14].y2, 'x2':tempList1[14].x2, 'y2':tempList1[14].y1};
list1Index['CSOP'] = {'x1': tempList1[15].x1, 'y1':tempList1[15].y2, 'x2':tempList1[15].x2, 'y2':tempList1[15].y1};
list1Index['Principal'] = {'x1': tempList1[16].x1, 'y1':tempList1[16].y2, 'x2':tempList1[16].x2, 'y2':tempList1[16].y1};
list1Index['DWS'] = {'x1': tempList1[17].x1, 'y1':tempList1[17].y2, 'x2':tempList1[17].x2, 'y2':tempList1[17].y1};
list1Index['Aberdeen Standard'] = {'x1': tempList1[18].x1, 'y1':tempList1[18].y2, 'x2':tempList1[18].x2, 'y2':tempList1[18].y1};
list1Index['ChinaAMC'] = {'x1': tempList1[19].x1, 'y1':tempList1[19].y2, 'x2':tempList1[19].x2, 'y2':tempList1[19].y1};

list2Index['BlackRock'] = {'x3': tempList2[0].x3, 'y3':tempList2[0].y3, 'x4':tempList2[0].x4, 'y4':tempList2[0].y4};
list2Index['Fidelity'] = {'x3': tempList2[1].x3, 'y3':tempList2[1].y3, 'x4':tempList2[1].x4, 'y4':tempList2[1].y4};
list2Index['SSgA'] = {'x3': tempList2[2].x3, 'y3':tempList2[2].y3, 'x4':tempList2[2].x4, 'y4':tempList2[2].y4};
list2Index['Hang Seng'] = {'x3': tempList2[3].x3, 'y3':tempList2[3].y3, 'x4':tempList2[3].x4, 'y4':tempList2[3].y4};
list2Index['UBS'] = {'x3': tempList2[4].x3, 'y3':tempList2[4].y3, 'x4':tempList2[4].x4, 'y4':tempList2[4].y4};
list2Index['Schroders'] = {'x3': tempList2[5].x3, 'y3':tempList2[5].y3, 'x4':tempList2[5].x4, 'y4':tempList2[5].y4};
list2Index['JP Morgan'] = {'x3': tempList2[6].x3, 'y3':tempList2[6].y3, 'x4':tempList2[6].x4, 'y4':tempList2[6].y4};
list2Index['Value Partners'] = {'x3': tempList2[7].x3, 'y3':tempList2[7].y3, 'x4':tempList2[7].x4, 'y4':tempList2[7].y4};
list2Index['First State'] = {'x3': tempList2[8].x3, 'y3':tempList2[8].y3, 'x4':tempList2[8].x4, 'y4':tempList2[8].y4};
list2Index['HSBC'] = {'x3': tempList2[9].x3, 'y3':tempList2[9].y3, 'x4':tempList2[9].x4, 'y4':tempList2[9].y4};
list2Index['Invesco'] = {'x3': tempList2[10].x3, 'y3':tempList2[10].y3, 'x4':tempList2[10].x4, 'y4':tempList2[10].y4};
list2Index['BOCI-Prudential'] = {'x3': tempList2[11].x3, 'y3':tempList2[11].y3, 'x4':tempList2[11].x4, 'y4':tempList2[11].y4};
list2Index['DWS'] = {'x3': tempList2[12].x3, 'y3':tempList2[12].y3, 'x4':tempList2[12].x4, 'y4':tempList2[12].y4};
list2Index['CSOP'] = {'x3': tempList2[13].x3, 'y3':tempList2[13].y3, 'x4':tempList2[13].x4, 'y4':tempList2[13].y4};
list2Index['Principal'] = {'x3': tempList2[14].x3, 'y3':tempList2[14].y3, 'x4':tempList2[14].x4, 'y4':tempList2[14].y4};
list2Index['Allianz'] = {'x3': tempList2[15].x3, 'y3':tempList2[15].y3, 'x4':tempList2[15].x4, 'y4':tempList2[15].y4};
list2Index['Manulife'] = {'x3': tempList2[16].x3, 'y3':tempList2[16].y3, 'x4':tempList2[16].x4, 'y4':tempList2[16].y4};
list2Index['Aberdeen Standard'] = {'x3': tempList2[17].x3, 'y3':tempList2[17].y3, 'x4':tempList2[17].x4, 'y4':tempList2[17].y4};
list2Index['ChinaAMC'] = {'x3': tempList2[18].x3, 'y3':tempList2[18].y3, 'x4':tempList2[18].x4, 'y4':tempList2[18].y4};
list2Index['Mirae Asset'] = {'x3': tempList2[19].x3, 'y3':tempList2[19].y3, 'x4':tempList2[19].x4, 'y4':tempList2[19].y4};

list2Index2['BlackRock'] = {'x1': tempList2[0].x3, 'y1':tempList2[0].y3, 'x2':tempList2[0].x4, 'y2':tempList2[0].y4};
list2Index2['Fidelity'] = {'x1': tempList2[1].x3, 'y1':tempList2[1].y3, 'x2':tempList2[1].x4, 'y2':tempList2[1].y4};
list2Index2['SSgA'] = {'x1': tempList2[2].x3, 'y1':tempList2[2].y3, 'x2':tempList2[2].x4, 'y2':tempList2[2].y4};
list2Index2['Hang Seng'] = {'x1': tempList2[3].x3, 'y1':tempList2[3].y3, 'x2':tempList2[3].x4, 'y2':tempList2[3].y4};
list2Index2['UBS'] = {'x1': tempList2[4].x3, 'y1':tempList2[4].y3, 'x2':tempList2[4].x4, 'y2':tempList2[4].y4};
list2Index2['Schroders'] = {'x1': tempList2[5].x3, 'y1':tempList2[5].y3, 'x2':tempList2[5].x4, 'y2':tempList2[5].y4};
list2Index2['JP Morgan'] = {'x1': tempList2[6].x3, 'y1':tempList2[6].y3, 'x2':tempList2[6].x4, 'y2':tempList2[6].y4};
list2Index2['Value Partners'] = {'x1': tempList2[7].x3, 'y1':tempList2[7].y3, 'x2':tempList2[7].x4, 'y2':tempList2[7].y4};
list2Index2['First State'] = {'x1': tempList2[8].x3, 'y1':tempList2[8].y3, 'x2':tempList2[8].x4, 'y2':tempList2[8].y4};
list2Index2['HSBC'] = {'x1': tempList2[9].x3, 'y1':tempList2[9].y3, 'x2':tempList2[9].x4, 'y2':tempList2[9].y4};
list2Index2['Invesco'] = {'x1': tempList2[10].x3, 'y1':tempList2[10].y3, 'x2':tempList2[10].x4, 'y2':tempList2[10].y4};
list2Index2['BOCI-Prudential'] = {'x1': tempList2[11].x3, 'y1':tempList2[11].y3, 'x2':tempList2[11].x4, 'y2':tempList2[11].y4};
list2Index2['DWS'] = {'x1': tempList2[12].x3, 'y1':tempList2[12].y3, 'x2':tempList2[12].x4, 'y2':tempList2[12].y4};
list2Index2['CSOP'] = {'x1': tempList2[13].x3, 'y1':tempList2[13].y3, 'x2':tempList2[13].x4, 'y2':tempList2[13].y4};
list2Index2['Principal'] = {'x1': tempList2[14].x3, 'y1':tempList2[14].y3, 'x2':tempList2[14].x4, 'y2':tempList2[14].y4};
list2Index2['Allianz'] = {'x1': tempList2[15].x3, 'y1':tempList2[15].y3, 'x2':tempList2[15].x4, 'y2':tempList2[15].y4};
list2Index2['Manulife'] = {'x1': tempList2[16].x3, 'y1':tempList2[16].y3, 'x2':tempList2[16].x4, 'y2':tempList2[16].y4};
list2Index2['Aberdeen Standard'] = {'x1': tempList2[17].x3, 'y1':tempList2[17].y3, 'x2':tempList2[17].x4, 'y2':tempList2[17].y4};
list2Index2['ChinaAMC'] = {'x1': tempList2[18].x3, 'y1':tempList2[18].y3, 'x2':tempList2[18].x4, 'y2':tempList2[18].y4};
list2Index2['Mirae Asset'] = {'x1': tempList2[19].x3, 'y1':tempList2[19].y3, 'x2':tempList2[19].x4, 'y2':tempList2[19].y4};

list3Index['BlackRock'] = {'x3': tempList3[0].x3, 'y3':tempList3[0].y3, 'x4':tempList3[0].x4, 'y4':tempList3[0].y4};
list3Index['Fidelity'] = {'x3': tempList3[1].x3, 'y3':tempList3[1].y3, 'x4':tempList3[1].x4, 'y4':tempList3[1].y4};
list3Index['SSgA'] = {'x3': tempList3[2].x3, 'y3':tempList3[2].y3, 'x4':tempList3[2].x4, 'y4':tempList3[2].y4};
list3Index['UBS'] = {'x3': tempList3[3].x3, 'y3':tempList3[3].y3, 'x4':tempList3[3].x4, 'y4':tempList3[3].y4};
list3Index['Hang Seng'] = {'x3': tempList3[4].x3, 'y3':tempList3[4].y3, 'x4':tempList3[4].x4, 'y4':tempList3[4].y4};
list3Index['Schroders'] = {'x3': tempList3[5].x3, 'y3':tempList3[5].y3, 'x4':tempList3[5].x4, 'y4':tempList3[5].y4};
list3Index['Value Partners'] = {'x3': tempList3[6].x3, 'y3':tempList3[6].y3, 'x4':tempList3[6].x4, 'y4':tempList3[6].y4};
list3Index['JP Morgan'] = {'x3': tempList3[7].x3, 'y3':tempList3[7].y3, 'x4':tempList3[7].x4, 'y4':tempList3[7].y4};
list3Index['First State'] = {'x3': tempList3[8].x3, 'y3':tempList3[8].y3, 'x4':tempList3[8].x4, 'y4':tempList3[8].y4};
list3Index['DWS'] = {'x3': tempList3[9].x3, 'y3':tempList3[9].y3, 'x4':tempList3[9].x4, 'y4':tempList3[9].y4};
list3Index['Invesco'] = {'x3': tempList3[10].x3, 'y3':tempList3[10].y3, 'x4':tempList3[10].x4, 'y4':tempList3[10].y4};
list3Index['HSBC'] = {'x3': tempList3[11].x3, 'y3':tempList3[11].y3, 'x4':tempList3[11].x4, 'y4':tempList3[11].y4};
list3Index['Allianz'] = {'x3': tempList3[12].x3, 'y3':tempList3[12].y3, 'x4':tempList3[12].x4, 'y4':tempList3[12].y4};
list3Index['BOCI-Prudential'] = {'x3': tempList3[13].x3, 'y3':tempList3[13].y3, 'x4':tempList3[13].x4, 'y4':tempList3[13].y4};
list3Index['CSOP'] = {'x3': tempList3[14].x3, 'y3':tempList3[14].y3, 'x4':tempList3[14].x4, 'y4':tempList3[14].y4};
list3Index['Aberdeen Standard'] = {'x3': tempList3[15].x3, 'y3':tempList3[15].y3, 'x4':tempList3[15].x4, 'y4':tempList3[15].y4};
list3Index['Principal'] = {'x3': tempList3[16].x3, 'y3':tempList3[16].y3, 'x4':tempList3[16].x4, 'y4':tempList3[16].y4};
list3Index['Manulife'] = {'x3': tempList3[17].x3, 'y3':tempList3[17].y3, 'x4':tempList3[17].x4, 'y4':tempList3[17].y4};
list3Index['ChinaAMC'] = {'x3': tempList3[18].x3, 'y3':tempList3[18].y3, 'x4':tempList3[18].x4, 'y4':tempList3[18].y4};
list3Index['Mirae Asset'] = {'x3': tempList3[19].x3, 'y3':tempList3[19].y3, 'x4':tempList3[19].x4, 'y4':tempList3[19].y4};

var bigList = [];
for (var k = 0; k <20; k++) {
  var thisManager = managerList[k].manager;
  let merged = {...list1Index[thisManager], ...list2Index[thisManager]};
  bigList.push(merged);
};

var bigList2 = [];
for (var k = 0; k <20; k++) {
  var thisManager = managerList[k].manager;
  let merged2 = {...list2Index2[thisManager], ...list3Index[thisManager]};
  bigList2.push(merged2);
};


  var polyMaster = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < bigList.length; k++) {
      var tempItem = [
        {'x':bigList[k].x1+4, 'y':bigList[k].y1},
        {'x':bigList[k].x2+4, 'y':bigList[k].y2+2},
        {'x':bigList[k].x3-4, 'y':bigList[k].y3+1},
        {'x':bigList[k].x4-4, 'y':bigList[k].y4-2},
      ];
      polyMaster.push(tempItem);
  }

  var polyMaster2 = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < bigList2.length; k++) {
      var tempItem = [
        {'x':bigList2[k].x1+4+120, 'y':bigList2[k].y2},
        {'x':bigList2[k].x2+4+120, 'y':bigList2[k].y1+2},
        {'x':bigList2[k].x3-4, 'y':bigList2[k].y3+1},
        {'x':bigList2[k].x4-4, 'y':bigList2[k].y4-2},
      ];
      polyMaster2.push(tempItem);
  }

graphGroup.selectAll(".poly1")
    .data(polyMaster)
  .enter().append("polygon")
    .attr('class','poly1')
    .attr("points",function(d) {
        return d.map(function(d) { return [d.x,d.y].join(","); }).join(" ");})
    .style('fill', function(d,i) {return colorMap[managerList[i].manager]})
    .style('opacity', .6);

    graphGroup.selectAll(".poly2")
        .data(polyMaster2)
      .enter().append("polygon")
        .attr('class','poly2')
        .attr("points",function(d) {
            return d.map(function(d) { return [d.x,d.y].join(","); }).join(" ");})
        .style('fill', function(d,i) {return colorMap[managerList[i].manager]})
        .style('opacity', .6);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```